# this.x = undefined, but objName.x works?

Tags: javascript, object

So lets say we have an object, foo, and in it we have 2 variables, one a string the other a number. Ex:

```
foo = {price:20,string:"bar "+this.price}
```

When i do this, calling console.log(foo.string) gives me

```
bar undefined
```

But if i were to do:

```
foo = {price:20,string:"bar "+this.price}
foo = {price:20,string:"bar "+foo.price}
```

It works as intended(obviously), whats the reason for this. not working?

Comment: because it is inside the object scope, you should use `this`, `foo` is `undefined` inside those `{}`

Comment: The second would only work if you previously made a `foo` definition, otherwise you would be getting a _"foo is no defined"_ or similar error. The first one doesn't work because `this` would not refer to the object that you are creating. You cannot reference an object that you are in the middle of creating.

Comment: I just realized i made an error in my debugging process....... let me fix that

Comment: my bad, but somehow, your second code won't work either. If you're doing it  in the console, it will work probably because you have already defined `foo` earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `this` for your object, you should use constructor functions to create objects.

```
function Foo(price) {
    this.price = price; // <-- now this will refer to this function scope when used with `new` keyword
    this.string = 'bar' + this.price;
}

a = new Foo(12);
a.price; // 12
a.string; // 'bar12'
```

Your code works because:

```
foo = {price:20,string:"bar "+this.price} // <-- foo was declared here
foo = {price:20,string:"bar "+foo.price} // <-- foo is available here
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp

Answer (score 2):

`this` here isn't what you think it is. It's in the global scope, so it is a reference to the `window` object, not a reference to the object you're creating.

Here is a proof:

```js
foo = {price:20,string:"bar "+this}

console.log(foo);
```

And since the `window` object doesn't have a property named `price`, then `widnow.price` is `undefined`.

When you do:

```
foo = {price:20,string:"bar "+this.price}
foo = {price:20,string:"bar "+foo.price}
```

The first line define `foo` as `{price:20,string:"bar undefined"}`, and then in the second line we already have a `foo` with its `price` property set to 20, so the second line results in `foo` set to `{price:20,string:"bar 20"}`.

Comment: Alright, this gives me a better understanding of that. But how would i use the object key 'price' as a part of another item inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined` comes from `window.price` being `undefined`, as `this`, in the global context, refers to `window`, as you can see in the first `console.log` here:

```js
console.log(`this === window = ${ this === window }`);

foo = { price:20, string: "bar " + this.price };

console.log(foo);
```

The second case only works because, in the first statement, you will define `foo` already, so when you execute the next statement, you will be redefining `foo` using the `foo.price` you defined previously, which is `20`:

```js
foo = { price:20, string: "bar " + this.price };

console.log("FIRST TIME =", foo);
console.log("Now foo.price =", foo.price);

foo = { price:20, string: "bar " + foo.price };

console.log("SECOND TIME =", foo);
```

If you only execute the second statement, it will throw an error, as `foo` wouldn't have been defined:

```js
foo = { price:20, string: "bar " + foo.price };
```